# Android Wifi Direct Speed

Tags: android, wifi-direct

I have been going over this Wifi Direct tutorial for Android:
[Android Wi-Fi Peer-to-Peer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html)

I created the Wifi Direct connection between two devices and I used java sockets to transfer a file, very much like the tutorial. However my transfer speed is usually around 11 Mbps, maybe a little less.

I was wondering if anyone has been able to get higher transfer rates(like 54 Mbps or 30Mbps) with Wifi Direct? I think it's supposed to be possible.

Comment: Please , be more specific .

Comment: Well I calculate the Mbps by looking at the duration it takes a 10 megabyte file to get transferred. It takes around 9-10 seconds. I feel like for a 54Mbps or 30Mbps connection, this duration should be much less. I was hoping if someone else had tried the tutorial code and are seeing the same transfer rates that I am seeing or not. I have tried this on Nexus 7 devices.

Comment: I have placed my two devices next to each other

Comment: @user3071358 did you get speed like 54Mbps?

Answer (score 2):

I am now working on some wifi-direct project and the speed really varies. Sometimes it could reach as much as 25Mbps but sometimes it is extremely slow - the worst time I experienced is that it took about 180 seconds to transfer only 2 MB. My opinion is that it highly depends on the wifi environment around the device.